# Apache2 - link DocumentRoot to subfolder on external drive but alter permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, root, symlink, webserver

I have an exfat formatted usb drive mounted at `/media/usb/drive1/` with root user via `/etc/fstab`. Now I would like to link my apache2 DocumentRoot which is located under `/var/www/websites/` to a subfolder on that usb drive but not moving it there. Like so

```
/media/usb/drive1/websites/ --> /var/www/websites/
```

The main intention is to make use of the external storage instead of the limited system storage while keeping the document root in place.

I've think about `symlink` and `mount` options but could not figure out how to apply different permissions on source and destination. The package [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/) seem to be the right choice for this task but the following configuration in `/etc/fstab` somehow blow up the webserver after a reboot.

```
bindfs#/media/usb/drive1/websites /var/www/websites fuse force-user=www-data,force-group=www-data,create-for-user=webmaster,create-for-group=webmaster,create-with-perms=0770,chgrp-ignore,chown-ignore,chmod-ignore 0 0
```

How can I achieve a symbolic link to my usb drive and alter the permissions so that I can jail the FTP user webmaster?

Comment: I think the problem could be related to the USB drive not being mounted yet when Apache is starting. A symbolic link should work fine as Apache will still see the `websites` entry and start. Any request while the USB is not mounted will return a 404, but once mounted will work correctly (just slower due to USB).

Comment: Is it possible that the folder `websites` on the already mounted usb drive can't be mounted? And what is the cleanest way of linking to the DocumentRoot: a symbolic soft-link or a mountpoint?